# How to fix "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {})

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm working on building a full stack website that uses React, Express, Sequalize and mySQL. It is so far running with features as register and login, but when I try to add error-handling it's failing.

I get the following error message:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in div (at Login.js:46)
    in form (at Login.js:44)
    in div (at Login.js:43)
    in div (at Login.js:42)
    in div (at Login.js:41)
    in Login (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:26)
    in Switch (at App.js:23)
    in div (at App.js:22)
    in div (at App.js:15)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:14)
    in App (at src/index.js:7)
```

When I add this code `{this.state.errenter code hereors}` in order to display error-messages such as "User cant be found".

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { login } from "./UserFunctions";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      errors: {}
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };

    login(user, (res, err) => {
      if (res) {
        this.props.history.push(`/`);
      } else {
        this.setState({
          errors: err
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
            <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
              <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                {this.state.errors}
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Enter email"
                  value={this.state.email}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
              >
                Sign in
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Appreciate any guidance on how can I can solve this one.

EDIT: Login function calls following function in backend:

```
users.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: req.body.email
    }
  })
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
          let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {


            expiresIn: 1440
          });
          res.send(token);
        }
      } else {
        res.status(400).json({ error: "User does not exist" });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).json({ error: err });
    });
});
```

and runs it through this middle-layer:

```
export const login = user => {
  return axios
    .post("users/login", {
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    })
    .then(response => {
      localStorage.setItem("usertoken", response.data);
      return response.data;
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.error;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

which is where (err) is defined.

Comment: `{this.state.errors}` needs to be a string if you want to display it this way, what's the output of `console.log(err)` inside `login(user, (res, err) => {` ( inside `onSubmit` ?

Comment: please provide the `login` function

Comment: @Taki, that is not displaying anything more then what's being thrown out in the console in the moment, a 400 (Bad request) containing json message: {"error":"User does not exist"}, which I want to display in {this.state.errors}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why you are getting this error?

Because  you are trying to render an object when doing `{this.state.errors}`.

> How to fix it?

First you need to provide what the `login` function is doing and what `err` is.

You probably want to get only the error string, but `err` is an object.

An as you can see in the error message

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {})

This means that `err` is an empty object. An this can be seeing in you state where you declare it as

```
this.state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    errors: {} // declaring it as an object
};
```

You should declare errors as a string

```
this.state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    errors: "" // declaring it as a string
};
```

Or, depending on what is `err` of the `login` function, it should contain some string to be rendered.

Comment: I changed errors to a string, but the message is still not passing through to {this.state.errors}. 

I've added more details above on what the login and err function is doing.
And right now when I press the "submit" button with empty values, the console is throwing a 400 (Bad request) containing json message: {"error":"User does not exist"}, which I want to display in {this.state.errors}.

Comment: @Ben you code don't make any sense. In the login function, it only recives one parameter `user`, but you call it with two parameters and the second one being a function. Please correct that if you have any typo

Answer (score 0):

The `err` object is most likely an instance of `Error` and if that's the case, it will contain a `message` property.

So, this should be what you want to display `{ this.state.errors.message }`

Comment: I tried this too and sadly, this did not help. I've added more details above on what the login and err function is doing. Could it be something in that code that is holding off the message value from being passed to { this.state.errors.message } ?